# Making an RSS news article page look "native" in ios app

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiwebview, rss

I am creating an RSS Reader ios app for work and I have everything that I need except that when the article is loaded it just loads the mobile view just as it would load when viewing on safari. They want it to look more "native" to the app, meaning just the title, photo and then then the articles text in plain underneath.

This is my first attempt at an app and I am using a project that was open free source code. This project uses MWFeedParser integrated into it which, from what i've read, can accomplish what I need to (I think). Can anyone who has done this before or knows how to do it be kind enough to take me through it? I've asked a similar question before but the answers were vague and still left me stuck.

If it helps, I have uploaded the full project on github here:

https://github.com/cpoti24/RSSReader

Please download it if you wish and run it yourself on xcode if that will help out. If you're able to do it and help me learn how, even better.

Thanks!

Comment: It seems you deleted and then reposted this exact same question because the first one was closed. Since this question has the same problems as the previous one, this will likely be closed too. Don't post a link to a project and expect people to spend lots of time doing your work for you. Instead, narrow down your question to a clear and specific problem.

Comment: The other question wan't closed, I deleted it becuase I felt I had written too much information that wasn't neccessary. I shortened the question and made it more specific. I didn't post the link to do the work for me, I posted it becuase I do not know which and how much of the code would be useful to look at for this question. This way, all the code for the project is in one place and available for viewing. As I mentioned, I am completly new to xcode. I have been stuck for weeks trying on my own, I am simply reaching out for any sort of step-by-step so that I may learn to do it on my own

Comment: Either way, this question is far too broad. Please click on the help link above and read about the types of question that should be asked here.

Comment: The `attributedText` on a `UITextView` will render HTML converted to an attributed string, iOS7+.  You can then override the font attributes...

Comment: @stevesliva Thank you for your reply and help. If possible, and you don't mind, do you think you could explain just a little more detail. I sort of understand what you are saying but I am completely new to this and have been using free open source code that had a lot already done, I've been using that for my project and my work has been trying to change the look of the app around to what my boss at my internship wnats it to look like, thank you

Comment: I have some sample code, but I need to dig it up.

Comment: @stevesliva thanks, take your time!